# How to fix 'Codility FrogJump' Algorithm?

Tags: java, algorithm

On Codility there's this problem of counting the minimal number of jumps a frog has to make to reach Y position.

The problem reads as follow:

```
A small frog wants to get to the other side of the road. The frog is currently located at position X and wants to get to a position greater than or equal to Y. The small frog always jumps a fixed distance, D.

Count the minimal number of jumps that the small frog must perform to reach its target.

given three integers X, Y and D, returns the minimal number of jumps from position X to a position equal to or greater than Y.

For example, given:

  X = 10
  Y = 85
  D = 30
the function should return 3, because the frog will be positioned as follows:

after the first jump, at position 10 + 30 = 40
after the second jump, at position 10 + 30 + 30 = 70
after the third jump, at position 10 + 30 + 30 + 30 = 100
```

I have "solved" the problem and gotten "3" as result, just like in the example. However when I submit my code, I only get 11% and fail every test aside from the example.

This is my code

```
int count = 0;

while(X <= Y){
X += D;
count++;
}       

return count;
```

On my code I basically count the jumps needed to reach Y, which is the position the frog wants to get to. I'm not properly understanding the problem? If so, what I am missing?

Comment: Do you get to see the tests that you failed? What about when `X = 10`, `Y = 20`, and `D=10`? What does your algorithm return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the condition

```
while(X <= Y)
```

to make a new jump. However, in the case where `X == Y`, you have already reached your goal and don't want to jump further. Hence, update to

```
while(X < Y) //as long as we have not reached the goal
```

Comment: That did the trick. Got 100% correctness, but failed the performance tests with a complexity of O(Y-X)

Comment: Think about how you can calculate the number of jumps directly from the distance and the jump size (how would you do it for jump size 1; how would you do it for jump size 2...).

Answer (score 3):

why use any loops here, loops are a costly affair. Just one line answer

```
function solution(X,Y,D) {
    return Math.ceil((Y-X)/D);
}
```

Comment: Could you explain your reasoning?

Comment: The minimum distance frog need to cross the road will be Y-X and in one jump if frog jumps D distance then if we divide the distance needed by one unit of distance covered by frog we would get total number of jumps needed and because we might not get the whole number we need to ceil it to cover frog's last jump.

Comment: This is O(1) constant while the loops are more than that

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution. You have distance which is calculated as Y-X. So you just need to divide and check divisibility:

```
    function solution(X,Y,D) {

    var distance = Y-X;
    var steps = distance/D;
    /* If steps number is rounded integer just return steps */
    if((steps*D) == distance && Number.isInteger(steps)) {
      return steps;
    } else {
/* if there is rest of division then just round it (to floor) and increase steps number for one */
      return Math.floor(steps)+1;
    }

    }

    console.log(solution(10,85,30)); /* 3 */
```

That is solution in JavaScript and complexity is basically O(1).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a rudimentary solution I just thought of posting

```
    def solution(X, Y, D):
        distance = Y-X
        if distance % D == 0:
            return distance // D
        elif distance == 0:
            return 0
        else:
            return (distance // D) + 1
        pass
```

This will give 100% in correctness and performance. `//` this is for getting quoient

Answer (score 0):

My solution with 100% codility acceptance result:

```
   double d = Y - X;
        Double dd = new Double(D);
        double result = d / dd;
        result = Math.ceil(result);
        
        Double ans = new Double(result);
      
        return ans.intValue();
```